# Assign Hotkey to Show/Hide face edges wires

Tags: edges, shortcut

I am trying to assign a shortcut that allows me to tick/untick the command shown in the second picture so that all the edges disappear.
I used a hotkey in a former version of Blender, but at the moment I am no longer able to assign that command. [image][image]

Answer (score 0):

I have assigned alt+f and it works now.
Anyway I remember very well I was able to use a single key in previous versions.